# Ajax request to c# with Electron, is it possible?

Tags: electron

I'm trying out electron js for the first. I like the idea of being able to pretty much write web technology for any platform.

However I was wondering if it was possible or the best way to make an ajax call to server side? C#, not node js. And explaination or a link to the information would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do it exactly the same you do it with javascript with libraries like axios:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('example.com/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Why adding axios? You can do it without libraries. Just use the build in fetch `fetch('example.com/user?ID=12345).then(.....).catch(.....)`

Comment: I know but I like axios better.